# Cannot set row to be selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one strange problem and don't have a clue how to solve it. Here it is: I have two forms. From first form I take row (with index), and data from that row I display in another form with possibility to edit those data. All the time I have index of that row from DataGridView in first form.
When I edit data in second form and press UPDATE button, I want those data to be applied in same that row in first form. 
Here is code with further info:

```
if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Index of row that must be selected is " + rowIndex);
    dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Now, when form2 is closed i want to check if i still have same row selected in first form, and if not, to select it. On line where i do .Selected = true; I get this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

MessageBox above that line gives me right index of that row... For example, my DatGridView have 100 rows and i work with row with index 5. That is why I don't understand why i get error with "index out of range"...
Why I can't select that row again?

Comment: try  `dataGridView.Row=rowIndex;` also check `rowIndex<dataGridView.Rows.Count`

Comment: I don't think you have to check and show messagebox, just select your row after closing form2 normally, in case it's already selected, our code seems to be redundant, but it's very less in term of performance cost.

Comment: @KingKing - I use MessageBox just to see if rowIndex is correct. Also, I tried to select that row right after i close form2, but nothing happens...

Comment: -1 down vote
 

Can you add the following to your message box:

MessageBox.Show("Index of row that must be selected is " + rowIndex + " dataGridView.Rows.Count = " + dataGridView.Rows.Count );

Comment: Try `dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[SomeVisibleColumnsIndex];